# Possible to delay a segue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, delay, segue

I have an app with many segues built in the storyboard and I would like to delay them to show a quick animation on the clicked button.

Is it possible to delay a segue without using segueWithIdentifier ? Using segueWithIdentifier means to delete all segues in storyboard for recreating them in code => More code, more time to dev, more bugs possibilities, heavier app to run... It's not my favorite solution.

Does anyone know if it is possible to delay a segue while still using the segue between 2 VC in storyboard ?

Thanks all,

Comment: Try not to use `sleep()`. The cleanest approach is to modify your segues so that they are linked to the UIViewController and use IBAction methods from your buttons to perform the animation and the invoke the segue. The other option is a custom segue

Comment: I would say, never ever use sleep().

Comment: I would also say never use `sleep()`. That is truly dreadful advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @Paulw11. Link your segues between view controllers, not from your button.

Then your IBAction method would invoke a UIView animation where the completion block invokes the segue.

And T_77's advice is terrible. Avoid sleep at all costs. It locks up the device. Bad, bad mojo.